# How to Display Date picker in Colorbox Popup in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

In Jquery application i'm using `Colorbox` plugin to display popup. All are working fine but in the date picker, it is working but not in the popup, it is showing on side corner of main application.

But other plugins are working fine. What happens to the date picker plugin?
Here is some sample code:

```
<link href="resources/css/date-picker.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/date-picker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        //Code for Date Picker 
    new datepickr('startDt', {
        'dateFormat' : 'd-M-Y'
    });
    new datepickr('endDt', {
        'dateFormat' : 'd-M-Y'
    });

});
</script>


 -----
 <form:input path="startDate" type="text" id="startDt" />
-------
----
```

Comment: Have you imported Jquery?

Comment: yes, all plugin are working, this is also working but displaying outside of Popup..

Comment: It is because you are not associating the date picker with your input id. Please pass the id to your jquery function.

Comment: Then pass the id `startDt` to the jquery as i have shown in my answer below. If that solves your answer please accept.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your input id for the date:

```
 <input id="mydate">
```

You can pass the id to the jquery function as follows:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
    //Code for Date Picker 
    $('#mydate').datepickr('startDt', {
    'dateFormat' : 'd-M-Y'
     });
    $('#mydate').datepickr('endDt', {
    'dateFormat' : 'd-M-Y'
 });
});
```